# The least poles a meromorphic functon can attain on a Riemann Surface of genus g

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am recently reading some materials about Riemann Surface. When I met Riemann Roch theorem, I came up with a question as follows:

If f is a non constant meromorphic function on a surface of genus g, n is the number of poles f have, counting multipliticy. What is the minimum of n, with respect to g?

In the case g = 0, n is not less than 1 for Liouville's theorem, in the case g = 1, n is not less than 2, because integration along the basic lattice is zero, while f can not be holomorphic, so it can not just have a simple pole. But when the genus is bigger, I can not proceed.

Thank you for any possible help.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure, but I think you’re looking for the *gonality*, which is another invariant of a curve, not only depending on its genus. It’s usually defined as the minimal degree of a nonconstant morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @Mindlack Nice imformation, thank you very much! I will try to learn something about this.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to treat this problem in the manner of differential geometry and topology?

Comment: They might be useful tools, but the issue with differential geometry and topology is that they have far too many morphisms, when compared to (holomorphic) maps of Riemann Surfaces.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you.